# openOptionsMenu(); ERROR in onCreate()

Tags: android, optionmenu

I'm trying to create an `OptionsMenu` dynamically at `Activity` startup. In the `onCreate` I call :

```
openOptionsMenu(); //here i get the error
closeOptionsMenu();
```

to create the menu, but i get the following error:

```
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.donauinvest.idealsfa/com.donauinvest.idealsfa.forme.ComenziForm}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:562)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:185)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:97)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:563)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:439)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.Activity.openOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2486)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at com.donauinvest.idealsfa.forme.ComenziForm.onCreate(ComenziForm.java:130)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
02-07 12:50:47.183: E/AndroidRuntime(31427):    ... 11 more
```

i'm creating the menu like this:

```
android.view.Menu mymenu=null;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) 
{
    menu.clear();
    SubMenu opMenu =  menu.addSubMenu(0, 0, 0, "Operatii");
    int lastindex=0;
    if (configurare.bChooseTipCda && istoric==0 && (clientid > 0))
    {
         TipComandaClass.setTipComandaContextForDB(this);
                tc = TipComandaClass.get_TipComanda();

         if (tc.size()>0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < tc.size(); i++)
            {
                opMenu.add(0,i,0,tc.get(i).getDenumire());
                lastindex=i;
            }
            lastindex++;
            opMenu.add(0,lastindex,0,"NOU");
            lastindex++;
            opMenu.add(0,lastindex,0,"DETALII");
         }
      }
      if (istoric==1 && configurare.bRetransmitereComanda)
      {    
          lastindex++;
          opMenu.add(0,lastindex,0,"RETRANSMITERE");
      }
      if (istoric == 1 && configurare.bInserareComandaIstoric)
      {
          lastindex++;
          opMenu.add(0,lastindex,0,"INSEREAZA");
      }  
      mymenu=menu;

      if (clientid > 0)
      {
          for (int i=0;i<mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().size();i++)
          {
          if (mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().equals("NOU"))
          {
                  mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(true);
              break;
          }
          }
      }
      else
      {
          for (int i=0;i<mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().size();i++)
                     {
                         if (mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().equals("NOU"))
                         {
                             mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
                             break;
                         }
                     }
              }

              if (listCom.size() > 0)
              {
                 for (int i=0;i<mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().size();i++)
                 {
                     if (mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().equals("DETALII"))
                     {
                         mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(true);
                         break;
                     }
                 }
              }
              else 
              {
                 for (int i=0;i<mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().size();i++)
                 {
                     if (mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().equals("DETALII"))
                     {
                         mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
                         break;
                     }
                 }
              }
              if (istoric == 1)
              {
                  for (int i=0;i<mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().size();i++)
                 {
                     if (mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).getTitle().equals("NOU"))
                     {
                         mymenu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
                         break;
                     }
                 }
              }

              if (listCom.size() > 0)
              {
                     mymenu.setGroupVisible(0, true);
              }
              else
              {
                     mymenu.setGroupVisible(0, false);
              }
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            return true;
      }//onCreateOptionsMenu
```

THANKS ADVANCED !

Comment: Why do you call openOptionsMenu() in onCreate() ? It's enough to override onCreateOptionsMenu() in your Activity and when the user clicks on the Menu button your menu will appear with the items you put in it.

Also, can you please paste here the rest of your Activity code?

Comment: the problem is that, i must enable/disable the menu items outside the  onCreateOptionsMenu(). therefore i use the mymenu variable.

Comment: i tried with this.openOptionsMenu() and ((Activity)this).openOptionsMenu(), but without luck. i have an activity in which this works, but if i try to make the same thing in other activities, the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like doing `openOptionsMenu()` in `onCreate` can cause problems. I successfully circumvented this issue by moving the call to `onResume`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```